# How to calculate p values of long-run coefficients in autoregressive distributed lag (ARDL) bound test approach

Tags: time-series, ardl

For example, I estimate an ARDL with two variables as follows.

D(xt) = a + D(xt-1) + D(yt-1) + xt-1 + yt-1 + e

where D refers to first order difference.

According to ARDL bound approach the long run coefficients are extracted by dividing coefficient on yt-1/xt-1.

My question is how do I calculate p value for my long-run coefficients when I divide one coefficient over another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms. What is ARDL?

Comment: @gung I edited the question. Autoregressive distributed lag. I'm familiar with distributed lag: adjusting for one or more exposure measurements $X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, \ldots$ against a future measurement of an outcome $Y_t$.

Answer (score 1):

> According to ARDL bound approach the long run coefficients are extracted by dividing coefficient on yt-1/xt-1.
>
> My question is how do I calculate p value for my long-run coefficients when I divide one coefficient over another?

I can't comment much on the validity of the model, especially without any substantive background on the approach, but the general question: how do I perform inference on a function of the regression coefficients, is relatively straightforward.

Assuming you fit the model you described you can easily calculate the CI and p-value for the estimate using the $\delta$-method. It's simply a matter of writing out the change-of-variable equations, calculating the Jacobian, and applying it to the variance-covariance matrix for the regression coefficients. In `R` obtaining the cov matrix for the betas is done by calling `vcov` on the model fit.

The change of variable formula is:

$f(y_{t-1}, x_{t-1}) = y_{t-1} / x_{t-1}$

So the gradient in question would be of the form:

$\nabla f(y_{t-1}, x_{t-1}) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 / x_{t-1} \\ -y_{t-1} / x_{t-1}^2\end{array} \right] $

Assigning these regression coefficients the values of $\beta_{lx}$ and $\beta_{ly}$ ($l$ for lag), you get the estimate:

$$\mbox{var} \left( \frac{\hat{\beta}_{ly}}{\hat{\beta}_{lx}} \right) = 
\nabla f(\hat{\beta}_{ly}, \hat{\beta}_{lx}) ^T \mbox{var} \left( [\hat{\beta}_{ly}, \hat{\beta}_{lx}] \right) \nabla f(\hat{\beta}_{ly}, \hat{\beta}_{lx}) 
$$

Comment: Could you please provide an R code with a simple example for this. I guess your method is too technical for me to implement in R. Thanks.